# R regex gsub separate letters and numbers

Tags: regex, r, gsub, stringr

I have a string that's mixed letters and numbers:

```
"The sample is 22mg"
```

I'd like to split strings where a number is immediately followed by letter like this:

```
"The sample is 22 mg"
```

I've tried this:

```
gsub('[0-9]+[[aA-zZ]]', '[0-9]+ [[aA-zZ]]', 'This is a test 22mg')
```

but am not getting the desired results.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use capturing parentheses in the regular expression and group references in the replacement.  For example:

```
gsub('([0-9])([[:alpha:]])', '\\1 \\2', 'This is a test 22mg')
```

There's nothing R-specific here; the R help for `regex` and `gsub` should be of some use.

Answer (score 12):

You need backreferencing:

```
test <- "The sample is 22mg"
> gsub("([0-9])([a-zA-Z])","\\1 \\2",test)
[1] "The sample is 22 mg"
```

Anything in parentheses gets remembered.  Then they're accessed by \1 (for the first entity in parens), \2, etc.  The first backslash escapes the backslash's interpretation in R so that it gets passed to the regular expression parser.