# Substituting the results of a calculation

Tags: r, mean, gsub, strsplit

I'm munging data, specifically, I've opened this pdf http://pubs.acs.org/doi/suppl/10.1021/ja105035r/suppl_file/ja105035r_si_001.pdf and scraped the data from table s4,

```
    1a 1b 1a 1b
1 5.27 4.76 5.09 4.75
2 2.47 2.74 2.77 2.80
4 1.14 1.38 1.12 1.02
6 7.43 7.35 7.22-7.35a 7.25-7.36a
7 7.38 7.34 7.22-7.35a 7.25-7.36a
8 7.23 7.20 7.22-7.35a 7.25-7.36a
9(R) 4.16 3.89 4.12b 4.18b
9(S) 4.16 3.92 4.12b 4.18b
10 1.19 0.91 1.21 1.25
```

pasted it into notepad and saved it as a txt file.

```
s4 <- read.table("s4.txt", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

gives,

```
   X1a  X1b      X1a.1      X1b.1
1 5.27 4.76       5.09       4.75
2 2.47 2.74       2.77       2.80
4 1.14 1.38       1.12       1.02
6 7.43 7.35 7.22-7.35a 7.25-7.36a
7 7.38 7.34 7.22-7.35a 7.25-7.36a
8 7.23 7.20 7.22-7.35a 7.25-7.36a
```

in order to use the data I need to change it all to numeric and remove the letters, thanks to this link [R regex gsub separate letters and numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605564/r-regex-gsub-separate-letters-and-numbers) I can use the following code,

```
gsub("([[:alpha:]])","",s4[,3])
```

I can get rid of the extraneous letters.

What I want to do now, and the point of the question, is to change the ranges,

```
"7.22-7.35" "7.22-7.35" "7.22-7.35"
```

with their means,

```
"7.29"
```

Could I use gsub for this? (or would I need to strsplit across the hyphen, combine into a vector and return the mean?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a single regex in `strsplit` for this task (removing letters and splitting):

```
s4[] <- lapply(s4, function(x) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) x
  else sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), "-|[[:alpha:]]"), 
              function(y) mean(as.numeric(y)))
})
```

The result:

```
> s4
   X1a  X1b X1a.1 X1b.1
1 5.27 4.76 5.090 4.750
2 2.47 2.74 2.770 2.800
4 1.14 1.38 1.120 1.020
6 7.43 7.35 7.285 7.305
7 7.38 7.34 7.285 7.305
8 7.23 7.20 7.285 7.305
```

Comment: thanks (and thanks to the other contributors) some v useful tips

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that seems to work right on the sample data:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(col){
  col <- gsub("([[:alpha:]])","", col)
  col <- ifelse(grepl("-", col), mean(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(col[grepl("-", col)], "-")))), col)
  as.numeric(col)
})

> df
#   X1a  X1b X1a.1 X1b.1
#1 5.27 4.76 5.090 4.750
#2 2.47 2.74 2.770 2.800
#4 1.14 1.38 1.120 1.020
#6 7.43 7.35 7.285 7.305
#7 7.38 7.34 7.285 7.305
#8 7.23 7.20 7.285 7.305
```

Disclaimer: It only works right if the ranges in each column are all the same (as in the sample data)

Answer (score 2):

something like that :

```
mean(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit("7.22-7.35","-"))))
```

should work (and correspond to what you had in mind I guess)

or you can do :

```
eval(parse(text=paste0("mean(c(",gsub("-",",","7.22-7.35"),"))")))
```

but I'm not sure this is simpler...

**To apply it to a vector :**

```
vec<-c("7.22-7.35","7.22-7.35")

1st solution : sapply(vec, function(x) mean(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x,"-")))))
2nd solution : sapply(vec, function(x) eval(parse(text=paste0("mean(c(",gsub("-",",",x),"))"))))
```

In both cases, you'll get :

```
7.22-7.35 7.22-7.35 
    7.285     7.285
```

Comment: I know you can use `sapply`... Either way, it seems like the OP has all his ranges the same anyway

Answer (score 0):

Also,

```
library(gsubfn)
indx <- !sapply(s4, is.numeric)
s4[indx] <- lapply(s4[indx], function(x) 
          sapply(strapply(x, '([0-9.]+)', ~as.numeric(x)), mean))

s4
#   X1a  X1b X1a.1 X1b.1
#1 5.27 4.76 5.090 4.750
#2 2.47 2.74 2.770 2.800
#4 1.14 1.38 1.120 1.020
#6 7.43 7.35 7.285 7.305
#7 7.38 7.34 7.285 7.305
#8 7.23 7.20 7.285 7.305
```